# java-pretty print sql query

Tags: java

Does someone have pretty_print function for print SQL query in java?

given string like:

**SELECT person_table.name FROM person_table JOIN person_person ON person_table.name=person_person WHERE person_table.name=dan**

The function will print:

**SELECT person_table.name**

**FROM person_table**

**JOIN person_person**

**ON person_table.name=person_person**

**WHERE person_table.name=dan**

or better?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The thing with that is that everyone has a different way of writing SQL - some people place the JOIN clause on the same line as the FROM, or keep the ON clause with the JOIN clause on the same line.

Answer (score 3):

You can take a look at [org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.SQLFormatter](http://ci.apache.org/projects/openjpa/trunk/javadoc/index.html).

Answer (score 2):

If you work with Hibernate try `org.hibernate.jdbc.util.FormatStyle.BASIC.getFormatter().format(yourNonFormattedSqlQueryString);`

Comment: Works for HQL too.